# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 83 resolved, but only shows 1 record instead of the expected 3 from query

Tags: php

Received an error message

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 ... on line 83

and not sure what it means.

The snippet of code with the function where the message comes from is

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $time = $row['vluchttijd'];
    function timeInWords($time) {
        list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);
        return (int)$hours .  " hrs " . (int)$minutes . " min";**
   }
```

Line 83 is:

```
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);
```

What am I missing here?

EDITED:
Now I get no error, but the query should have 3 results and now I only get 1.

Also I had to add one more line, so now the code looks like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $time = $row['vluchttijd'];
    if (!function_exists('timeInWords')) {
    function timeInWords($time) {
        list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);
        return (int)$hours .  " hrs " . (int)$minutes . " min";
   }    $result = mysql_query($sql);

{
```

Comment: `var_dump( explode(':', $time) );` gives you an array of length >=2?

Comment: Expanding on @kingkero, I'm assuming your time does not contain `:` so there isn't a second value to be assigned to `$minutes`.

Comment: The field vluchttijd is a time database field, ie: 12:30. The function  is to convert the 12:30 into 12 hours 30 minutes.

it works perfectly on a different page, but it's not exactly the same setup - a single page with a html template. This one needs to be able to show multiple "records" within a "template".

Comment: @kingkero I had to add back  if (!function_exists('timeInWords')) {  and then it worked to a point. Now instead of displaying all 3 records for this one query, it only shows 1. [oh, and there should have been an = in line 1